# Difference between HDP Repo vs Apache tarball release

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, bigdata

I am trying to build a big-data platform with the tools hadoop, hive, hbase, pig, hive, storm, zookeeper through Ambari. Should we use only HDP or is there any other Apache Repository is available? If no, any enterprise licence required for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Primer**: Ambari is a tool that allows you to provision, manage, and monitor a hadoop cluster. An Ambari 'stack' is a group of services that are available to be provisioned in a stack.

**Answer**: HDP is a stack that is maintained by Hortonworks. There are other stacks from other providers:

- IBM has the IBM Open Platform (IOP, formerly known as BigInsights)
- Pivotal has PHD.

None of these products (HDP, IOP, PHD) require enterprise licenses they are all open source and free to use.